# Pause a sub-process BPMN

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, lucidchart

I've recently started at a new business and some of the processes are becoming a bit of a challenge to map out. Quite frequently we have a process that needs to go "on hold" when an event, which can occur at any point, is triggered. The problem I'm having mapping this out correctly is how to "restart" the process from where it left off, since it can effectively pause/unpause at any point.

Here's what I currently have:

[Process Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo8AO.png)

Basically, I need to have "Something Happened 2" not fully interrupt the sub-process, it just needs to put it on "hold". The actual situation is essentially that a customer can make a complaint while we handle their overdue bill, so we put the process on hold wherever it was at until we resolve the complaint, and then restart the process.

I'm not entirely sure the best approach to documenting this and couldn't find anything clear in the documentation, since a non-interupting event seems to have the rest of the process still continue forward in parallel.

Any help would be majorly appreciated.

Comment: I have just created a proposal for a new community that only deals with business process modeling because I noticed that many business-related questions around process modeling are lost amongst the software-focussed questions around modeling apps in the stackexchange community. Feel free to have a look and I am looking forward to your inputs regarding the community's future ! : https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121238/business-process-modeling?referrer=IU7kc0WmXuuHw8-vDBM9aw2

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to restart the whole sub-process from the beginning, then you could frontload an exclusive gateway. Once the complaint is dealt with, you can direct the sequence flow to that gateway, which would restart the sub-process. See below for an example (I have simplified your diagram a bit).

[image]